# Node.js and getting db-mysql to work

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm having a hard time learning node.js although I'm quite literal with JavaScript I cannot get the following example to work. I want to use this library: http://nodejsdb.org/

```
var mysql = require('db-mysql');
new mysql.Database({
    hostname: 'localhost',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'test'
}).on('error', function(error) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' + error);
}).on('ready', function(server) {
    console.log('Connected to ' + server.hostname + ' (' + server.version + ')');
}).connect();
```

2 Questions: What code would you wrap around above to get this to work and how would you design a node application that simply

a) retrieves values from a webpage
b) stores them into mysql
c) queries this sql database and display the results

Answer (score 0):

a) See the [`http.get(options, callback)`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http.get) function.

b,c) See the [db-mysql `query()` documentation](http://nodejsdb.org/docs/#database_query).

For example (untested):

```javascript
//...
}).on('ready', function(server) {
  var mysql = this;
  http.get(options, function(res) {
    res.on('data', callback(data)) {
      // Parse the respsonse document here and extract data of interest.
      var data1, data2; //...
      // Insert the data into the database.
      mysql.query()
      .insert('mytable', ['column1', 'column2'], [data1, data2])
      .execute(function(error, result) {
        if (error) throw error;
        // Handle query result...
      });
    });                   
    });
  }).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
  });
}).connect();
```

Comment: I was hoping for a bit more elaborate explanation ie how to get above code to work.